# CMake for Android with Qt Creator - Bug

Tags: android, c++, qt, gcc, cmake

I noticed a strange behavior on CMake for Android with Qt Creator. Apparently this seems to be a bug that was [reported](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36384) for a while, but so far with no apparent solution yet.

Here are steps taken, and the behavior as follows:

- Installed CMake with no problem on Ubuntu, then
- CMake option appears on Qt Creator

So, on Qt creator when I do:

- New Project > Projects > Non Qt Project > Plain C++ Project (CMake Build):: Choose :: Location:: Name [CMakeTest] :: Next > Finish... it gives the message:

  Qt Creator has no kits that are suitable for CMake projects. 
  Please configure a kit [Show Options].

Clicking on [Show Options]:: Build & Run > Kits > Auto-detected : Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1); Then still on :: Build & Run > CMake > Executable: I included:

```
/usr/bin/cmake [x] Prefer Ninja generator (CMake 2.8.9 or higher required).
```

To check if the CMake version is ok, terminal I run:

```
$ cmake -version 
cmake version 2.8.11.2.
```

Considering it possibly as a bug, any suggestion for a workaround?